# Can't click Field in GridView which has own GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I had adapter for GridView which has 2 ImageView and 2 TextView.

I setOnItemClickListener this GridView and it worked great.
I wanted add to this adapter another GridView(which has another adapter(with TextView and ImageView).

So, every field in main GridView has images, texts and small GridView. I can click "large" fields when small GridView is empty. When I add something to this small GridView it looks like I wanted but then I can't click "Large" fields, only these "small".
I tried to setFocusable, Clicable etc. to false but I can still click only "small" fields.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's question or your answer :P Yes, it's nested gridviews. How I can make outer GridView clickable?

Comment: Its a question generally nested gridviews are not used

Comment: Simplify, I want to have grid of fields which have image, text and small icons on each but I don't want click small icons but whole fields.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it's working when I add:

```
holder.internalGrid.setFocusable(false);
holder.internalGrid.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

in outer GridView adapter. I don't know why that does not work when I put this in xml.